# Restrict Switch Statement order

Tags: java

I am writing a menu in java using a switch statement and while loop. I am looking to find a way of ensuring the user completes menu one before proceeding to menu two.

Here is an example piece of code:
(Please note I normally pass data using setters and getters, this is just a quick program I wrote for this question)

```
package menuOrder;
```

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    int option = 0;
    String Fname = null;
    String Sname = null;
    int Age = 0;



    while(option !=5){

        System.out.println("1. Enter Firstname");
        System.out.println("2. Enter Surname");
        System.out.println("3. Enter Age");
        System.out.println("4. Display Details");
        System.out.println("5. System Exit");

        option = sc.nextInt();

        switch(option){

        case 1:
            System.out.println("Please enter your Firstname >");
            Fname = sc.next();

            break;

        case 2:
            System.out.println("Please enter your Surname >");
            Sname = sc.next();

            break;

        case 3:
            System.out.println("Please enter your Age >");
            Age = sc.nextInt();

            break;

        case 4:
            System.out.println("Firstname = " + Fname + "\nSurname = " + Sname + "\nAge = " + Age);
            break;

        case 5:
            System.out.println("You have chosen to System Exit!!!");
            System.exit(0);

            break;

            default:
                System.out.println("Invalid Entry!! \nPlease try again");
        }


    }

}
```

}

I am trying to prevent the use from entering their Surname before their Firstname.

Can someone please help?

Thanks

Comment: *I am trying to prevent the use from entering their Surname before their Firstname.* **Why?** Your code looks like that should work fine.

Comment: How about not using switch at all ? That seems to be the simplest solution

Comment: Maybe an If block inside the case statement for all of the input options. The If statement skipping if the data has already been input

Comment: This is just a simple program that is similar to my Graded Unit project. I have got to use a Switch statement to allow my project to work. My project is a Hotel Reservation System and the first two menu options are Register and login. The user has to register before logging in.

Answer (score 0):

First show only the first name. Then when the user enters first name call surname method from that method.Use method calls instead of switch case.

Comment: Don't use switch. Use method calls from one method to another in a sequence you want. In that way the user gets to enter the surname only after he enters first name.

Comment: Please see comment above.

Comment: I did not understand the use of switch. If you could explain in detail, i might be able to help you.

Comment: Sorry for taking a while to reply. I have had a busy weekend with other projects.

Comment: I can't share my Graded Unit project because it is an exam and it is confidential. But I can explain it as best as I can in detail.

Comment: Basically I am writing a Hotel Reservation program and below is the menu options:

Comment: 1. Register
2. Login
3. Discounts
4. Save and Exit

Comment: I simply want to stop the user from trying to login before they register.

Comment: Thanks for your help

Comment: I would love helping. First thing here is that switch loop cannot help you in any way. This can be done using many other ways.